# Draw qualitative plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, draw

I use LaTex regularly, but I'm new to the whole drawing thing. I'm writing my thesis about neural networks, and to illustrate a spike I want to plot something like this:
[image: spike]
In this case I'm not interested in the numbers, I just want something that resembles the form qualitatively.

My question: is there a way to qualitatively draw plots? Like describing the general form (in this case some thing like "0.5-1.5: gaussian shaped; 1.5-5: Lennard-Jones shaped" or something) or do I have to plot the specific formula?

Comment: No, there is no such way (you have functions that relies in some parameters). But you can try to define a piecewise function with variable parameters using PGFPlots, for example. Anyway, whatever you want to draw with TikZ/PGF (or similars) requires mathematics, i.e., numbers.

Comment: @audiophiel Could a solution with no formulas but with some coordinates (Bézier curve) be good for you?

Comment: @CarLaTeX thats what i basically did, but with inkscape (vector drawing tool) and imported it as .pdf_tex, so at least the labels etc are nicely rendered.

Comment: @audiophiel It could be done also with tikz, if you're interested I'll try to do it

Comment: @CarLaTeX thats very kind of you! but thanks, im good with my solution, and  already looked into Bézier curves via tikz, so i think i'm able to do the upcoming graphs there by my self:)

Comment: @audiophiel would you like to share your solution here so this question can have a complete answer?

Comment: @DaiBowen i've just drawn the graph in inkscape, sorry no fancy latex solution...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in the comments.

Comment: For curve sketching have a look at the way metapost does this and the implementation in `tikz` via the `hobby` library.